# Error: Command '['H:\\Django Practice\\My_Blog_project\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']

Tags: django

Error: Command '['H:\Django Practice\My_Blog_project\env\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.